# Ununtu 20 + Rancher 1.6 — 80 port issue

Tags: docker, ubuntu, iptables, rancher

I have two servers running Ubuntu 20.04 (fresh intallation), each has Docker installed. One of the servers (*Server A*) hosts Rancher 1.6 (rancher/server), while another one (*Server B*) has rancher/agent. Both servers have an Nginx container installed in Rancher, and the Nginx containers on both servers are configured with port forwarding set to 80->80 and 443->443.

**Problem:**

Server A: Everything works as expected without any issues.

Server B: It doesn't respond to requests on port 80 or any other port.

I have tried various methods to make it work. If I manually start a container without Rancher, using a command like `docker run -d -p 8081:80 --name my-service nginx:latest`, it handles requests on port 8081 and displays Ngnix welcome page.
However, if I change the command to `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-service nginx:latest` — I am unable to reach the host.

When using `tcpdump port 80`, I can see that the requests are reaching the server.

The command `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` gives the following output:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10038/docker-proxy
```

Going back to Rancher: If I change container's network settings from "Managed" to "Bridge", it successfully forwards any port except for port 80. For example: 8082->80 works fine, 8000->80 works fine, but 80->80 results in "Host unreachable" error. If I change network settings back to "Managed", no port forwarding works at all. I don't understand why this issue is occurring because on *Server A*, everything works fine with the default settings.

I have spent a couple of days already reading about iptables and other related topics, reinstalling Ubuntu, Docker, Rancher, but I have not achieved any results.

I hope someone can help me identify the problem.

**UPD:** after reinstalling Ubuntu and installing Docker and rancher/agent I found out that the 80th port got blocked after ipsec-* containers (created by rancher/agent) started. It haven't helped to solve the problem yet, however the breakpoint has been found.

Here are two outputs of iptables -L: before rancher/agent installed — https://pastebin.com/UtYjnqQM and after — https://pastebin.com/tpatsQfU

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble using port 80. I know you studied `iptables` but I suspect there is a firewall rule blocking that port. (`tcpdump` bypasses `iptables` so it's no help in ascertaining whether there is a firewall problem.) This may be tricky to debug, but issue an `iptables -L --verbose --numeric` and look for counts of (I think) `REJECT`ed packets (worth also looking at `DROP`ped packets). Try flooding port 80 and see if these counts increment accordingly.

Comment: Also may I suggest posting this to serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Wait, you didn't say _both_ servers are configured to forward port 80 to port 80 and port 443 to port 443, did you? If so you can't do that. If not, try this. Turn off all your Docker containers, Rancher, Nginx, etc. Then open two windows.  In one, type `sudo nc -l -p 80` (that's a lowercase L). (You may have to install `netcat-openbsd`.) In the other, type `echo hello, world | nc localhost 80`. You should see "hello, world" on the first terminal. If you can't do this, your port 80 is not working and is likely being firewalled. You can use `hping3` to verify.

Comment: I have just tried that trick with `nc` and there was nothing in the first terminal window. How can 80 port be firewalled if `ufw status` reports inactive? Are there ways to detect which application blocks it?

Comment: `ufw` is only one `iptables` client. You (or some other app) can configure `iptables` independently of `ufw`. If you do a `sudo iptables -L --verbose --numeric`, do you see any rules? It should just show three "Chains", each with a header that starts with `pkts`, the rest blank.

Comment: There are lots of "Chains", most of which were created with Rancher or Docker, like: "CATTLE_FORWARD", "DOCKER", "DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1" and so on. How can I find, which one blocks port?

Comment: Hmm. I have Docker running and I don't see those; did you shut down all your containers? Anyway, if you do a `sudo iptables -L --numeric | egrep '(REJECT|DROP)' | grep :80` do you see any output?

Comment: Yes, I shut down all containers before running that command. And here you can see full result: https://pastebin.com/UtYjnqQM As for the command with egrep, it returns nothing :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254392/discussion-between-vercingatorix-and-rodion-baskakov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I haven't found an answer to this question, I'm posting the solution I found.

As I mentioned before, *Server B* stopped responding to requests on port 80 after rancher/agent had started its services. When I ran the command `iptables -nvL -t nat | grep docker0` I received a response that had two peculiar rows:

```
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 to:10.42.125.250:80
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 to:10.42.125.250:443
```

These entries seemed strange to me because I hadn't started any containers using those ports on the server. However on *Server A*, where rancher/server is running, there is a Nginx container that uses ports 80 and 443. So, I stopped that container on *Server A*, and those entries dissapered. Then, I added an Nginx container on *Server B* with port forwarding set to 80:80 using the Rancher UI, and it became accessible. Finally, I started Nginx container on *Server A*, and now they work independently, forwarding ports on the respective servers where they reside.

It seems that Rancher propagates iptables rules to other containers if there is no service using ports 80 and 443.

I hope this information is helpful.